# SQL Grouping by multiple columns + summing the results of the third based on time

Tags: sql

Help to compose sql query

| ID1 | ID2 | winer | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaaaa | bbbbbb | bbbbbb | 2020-06-10 15:20:00 |
| bbbbbb | cccccc | 0 | 2020-06-12 15:20:00 |
| cccccc | aaaaaa | aaaaaa | 2020-06-22 15:20:00 |

At a certain time interval, which is indicated by two dates, make a grouping by each ID that may be present in the ID1 and ID2 columns, indicating the number of wins, draws and losses. The winner is determined by his ID, a draw is zero

---

Let's say in this table
3 unique IDs and the query would result in a table

---

| ID | win | lose | draw |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaaaa | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| bbbbbb | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| cccccc | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It may not best solution but you can try this one.

First let call your table `play`

Than use subquery to make `win`, `loss`, and `draw` column and create view to simplified it.

```
create or REPLACE view player_extended as (
select  table2.*,
        case when table2.status = "win" then table2.total else 0 end as win,
        case when table2.status = "loss" then table2.total else 0 end as loss,
        case when table2.status = "draw" then table2.total else 0 end as draw
    from (
        select table1.player, table1.status, count(*) as total
        from (
            SELECT player1 as player, winer,
                (CASE
                    WHEN player1 = winer THEN 'win'
                    WHEN player2 = winer THEN 'loss'
                    ELSE 'draw'
                END) as status
            FROM play
            UNION all
            SELECT player1 as player, winer,
                (CASE
                    WHEN player2 = winer THEN 'win'
                    WHEN player1 = winer THEN 'loss'
                    ELSE 'draw'
                END) as status
            FROM play
        ) table1
        group by table1.player, table1.status
    ) as table2
)
```

Then use sum on each column

```
select 
    player, 
    sum(total) as total,
    sum(win) as win, 
    sum(loss) as loss, 
    sum(draw) as draw 
from player_extended 
group by player
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MS SQL SERVER

;with cte as (
select
t.ID1,
isnull((select count(tt.winer) from @tbl tt where tt.winer=t.ID1 group by tt.winer),0)  as win,
isnull((select count(tt.winer) from @tbl tt where tt.winer=t.ID2   group by tt.winer),0)  as lose,
(select count(*) from @tbl tt where tt.ID1=t.ID1 or tt.ID2=t.ID1) as TotalTry
 from @tbl t
 group by ID1,ID2
)
select cte.ID1 as id,cte.win,cte.lose,(cte.TotalTry - (cte.win+cte.lose)) as Draw
from 
    cte 
order by 
    ID1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest unpivoting your table and then using conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(case when id = win then 1 else 0 end) as num_wins,
       sum(case when win = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_draws,
       sum(case when id <> win and win <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_loses
from ((select id1 as id, win from t) union all
      (select id2 as id, win from t)
     ) i
group by id;
```